# Authenticate to gcp container registry with many devices

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-container-registry

What authentication strategy would you use to allow 100s of devices in the field to log in to gcp cloud container registry in order to pull images?

Keep in mind that it must be possible to revoke acces on an individual basis.

Also these are automated machines not tied to a human user identity.

My first thought was to use service accounts, but I discovered there’s a hard limit of 100 in them.

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts could be the way to go if you need to auth every device separately against the registry. If you need to create more than 100 of them you should get in touch with your Customer Engineer/Support team, etc. it is entirely possible to do if you get your project whitelisted for that.

> You can create 100 service accounts in a project. Contact your account
>   manager if you need to create more than 100 service accounts in a
>   project.
>   https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#what_is_the_maximum_number_of_service_accounts_i_can_have_in_a_project